# Using relative layout placement on android

Tags: android

I may be trying to do something that is not possible. I am writing an app that is using a picture of a remote control as its background, and then I am placing buttons on top of the background using relative layout and margins to position the buttons correctly. I thought I would be able to specifiy different margins in different layout files, but it will only take the margins from the main layout file (the one in /layout). I have two layouts for xxhdpi and xhdpi, and the proper graphics are being picked up, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to move them a different amount based on the screen size. I can get one screen size to look fine, but then the other ones are messed up, no matter what I put in the respective xml files. Is it even possible to do this?

Thanks....

Comment: If you try to do this with pre-existing Layouts and Views, you're probably better off using rows with horizontal `LinearLayout`s filled with `Button`s, weighting the `Button`s' widths and the `LinearLayout`s' heights. However, I would think that you'll get a more consistent result if you subclass `View` and handle the drawing and click events yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create dimens file under various values folders (values,values-ldpi-v6, values-mdpi-v6 etc.) to specify different margins and the system will automatically pick the relevant values based on the screen resolution.

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="call_log_margin">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="no_call_log_margin_left">10dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Use these values "call_log_margin" and "no_call_log_margin_left" in your layouts .These will have different values in different dimens.xml

Comment: That was the missing ingredient. Thanks, all things seem to be lining up correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

you can place the relative layout anywhere on the view in run time.  Here is the sample code this may help you.

```
RelativeLayout DispView = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams DispViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w,h);
DispViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, someview.getId());
DispViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, someview2.getId());
DispViewLayoutParams.setMargins(x,y,0,0);
Mainview.addView(DispView , DispViewLayoutParams );
```